# What is the sum degrees of all the angles inside a triangle?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm going a little crazy, I don't want to repeat "of"...which question is the most suitable?

> What is the sum degrees of all interior angles of a triangle?

> What is the sum degrees of all the angles inside a triangle?

Comment: What is the sum, in degrees, of all the angles inside a triangle?

Comment: Why don't you want to repeat *of*?  There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: In degrees, what is the sum of a triangle's interior angles?

Comment: I just think the repetation can be avoided if possible

Answer (score 1):

If you really must avoid repeating "of", you could instead say:

> What is the **total** of the angles inside a triangle?

"Sum" and "total" are different things - 'sum' means *a quantity obtained by addition or aggregation*, whereas 'total' means *an amount obtained by the addition of smaller amounts*.

> "All triangles have angles that total 180 degrees"
> -*Cambridge Primary Mathematics Stage 6 Teacher's Resource*

Comment: sum noun (TOTAL) the whole number or amount when two or more numbers or amounts have been added together: The sum of 13 and 8 is 21. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sum)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, you've just added two smaller amounts in a sum. That's not how the example in the OP is written, I don't see the relevance of this comment?

Comment: I find _the total degrees_ unacceptable. _total_ requires a dimension, not a unit _the total weight, length, distance_, not _*the total kilos, metres, miles_.

Comment: @ColinFine Agreed, I should have changed that to 'angles'.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask:

> What is the sum of the interior angles in a triangle?

And you can add "In degrees" if you think anyone in the class is likely to know any other unit (if you are asking this question, it's unlikely that they have studied radians)

The phrase "sum degrees"  doesn't work, but "angle sum" is possible

> What is the interior angle sum of a triangle?

However there is no reason to avoid the repetition of "of".

> What is the sum of the degrees of all interior angles of a triangle?

You should avoid repetition of major words, but it is common and normal to repeat words like "of".

> Tell me of the evaluation of the geometric mean of log10 values of prime numbers.